# Using CSS3 instead of images to achieve desired results

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use CSS3 instead of images to code the menu in http://www.cssmania.com/ .

My code so far (& the images+styles) can be found here:
http://sarahjanetrading.com/js/j

I tried using CSS3 to achieve the border shadow and the menu li a background to match the one in http://www.cssmania.com. But it just doesnt look the same. When I tried using images, it looked almost perfect. But I want to use CSS3 to achieve the result.

I tried inspecting the code on cssmania.com, but couldnt find the ones for the menu border to make it look the way it is, and the menu li background. I just want the code for these two functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing I see that stands out different is the background of the links.  There's a subtle gradient on the original design, and that's missing from yours.  It's also why the borders look different - the gradient is on the color, not the borders, but your eye is tricked.

Add this to the stylesheet:

```
#header-mania .header {

    /* Keep everything *except* the original background */

    background: #7fa445;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7fa445 0%, #6b9632 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7fa445), color-stop(100%,#6b9632));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7fa445 0%,#6b9632 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7fa445 0%,#6b9632 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7fa445 0%,#6b9632 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7fa445', endColorstr='#6b9632',GradientType=0 );
    background: linear-gradient(top, #7fa445 0%,#6b9632 100%);
}
```

That background's color might not be exact (I didn't feel like firing up PS just to match the colors), but you can adjust the colors easily using [the Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: Oh, and you might want to add `body{ margin: 0; }` to prevent the white border. ;-)

Comment: Hrm, I just noticed you are still using an image for the partial white circle at the bottom.  You *might* be able to code that circle using pure CSS3, but I think it wouldn't be worth the effort.  If you don't need to support IE 7 or older, you could use [Data URIs](http://css-tricks.com/5970-data-uris/) to embed the image.

Comment: thanks ALOT overZealous ! You are a life-saver !...Thanks for taking the time to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned your version of the menu doesn't look too different, in fact if you inspect css mania's stylesheet files they're only using `text-shadow` declarations on the elements, everything else is achieved with images. Hope you find my comments helpful!

Comment: the border looks different, and so does the menu a background. I want them to look like the ones in cssmania.com, but i'm guessing they're using images because i couldnt find it on the stylesheets. I just want these two things to look similar. Thanks